# make textfield become first responder

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

In my table I use `UITextField` istead of `UILabel` (with `enabled = 0`).

Now pressign an add button, the last cell shall become editable. I tried the following:

```
UITextField *textField = [subviewsOfCell ObjectAtIndex:index];
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

but I doesn't get it editable. (I know that I get the correct cell, because `textField.text = @"test";` displays correctly). What must I do?

Comment: Are you re-enabling the UITextField before making it the first responder?

Answer (score 2):

Just try doing this:

```
UITextField *textField = [subviewsOfCell ObjectAtIndex:index];
textField.enabled = YES;
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you, great other soul on SO, for reminding me that a textfield must be enabled to become first responder.